# How can I clear a control binding?

Tags: elite-dangerous

The alpha build of Elite: Dangerous doesn't appear to have a button to clear a control binding, or any indication of how to clear a control binding.

In my particular instance, I was playing with a mouse so was using the "Mouse and Keyboard" profile, which has bound my mouse to ship movements, but now I am playing with a gamepad and want to clear the mouse controls without changing my profile (since I've bound a variety of other controls since, and have already bound my gamepad).

How can I clear a control binding that has been set and reset it to nothing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the particular instance in the question of unbinding the mouse, this is different from unbinding the other controls. To prevent mouse movement controlling your ship, simply change "Mouse Mode" to **OFF** in the control bindings screen.

[image]

To unbind any of the other controls, you need to do the following - while the interface doesn't give any specifics on clearing control bindings, the process is straight forward;

- Find the thing you want to unbind
- Click it so that it prompts you to select a new binding
- Press <kbd>ESC</kbd>

[image]

This will clear the binding and reset it back to nothing. You should note that while pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd> will exit the control binding screen, you must click the Apply button in order to actually save your changes on this screen first.